# Write database table to a List

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I built a function to query specific tables in a sqlite database based on the table name. Right now my debug line returns the correct information. The next thing I would like to do is to write this data to a list. How would I do that?

```
public void RetrieveDriftData(string driftID)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM \"" + driftID + "\" ";
        GameManager.Drift = dbManager.Query<Drift>(sql);

        foreach (Drift drift in GameManager.Drift)
        {
            Debug.Log(drift.DriftStep);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is how to create a list from your enumerable...

```
public void RetrieveDriftData(string driftID)
{
    string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {driftID}";
    GameManager.Drift = dbManager.Query<Drift>(sql);

    var driftList = GameManager.Drift.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [List(T) class for C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don't need any specific customization.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<Drift > driftList = new List<Drift>();

...

public void RetrieveDriftData(string driftID)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM \"" + driftID + "\" ";
    GameManager.Drift = dbManager.Query<Drift>(sql);

    foreach (Drift drift in GameManager.Drift)
    {
        Debug.Log(drift.DriftStep);
        driftList.Add(drift);
    }
}
```